# What occurs when I use redirection without leading commands?

Tags: bash

I saw these commands (checking tcp port is listening or not):

```bash
while ! > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080; do
  echo "waiting..."
  sleep 3
done
```

I'm struggling to understand what's going on  inside `while`.

```
! > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080
```

Is this valid bash script? I tested it and understood that this just open file (or create one).

Is redirection without command specified on official document?

Comment: `LESS='+/Redirecting Output' man bash`

Comment: [Redirecting Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this valid bash script?

> Is redirection without command specified on official document?

**TL;DR:** Yes, it is valid. No, redirection without a command is not documented, but that's not what you have.

#### Generalities

Bash conforms generally to the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01), though it provides some extensions and deviates in some ways (much less so when its POSIX conformance mode is engaged).  That document is a pretty good basis, but the most pertinent and official document available for Bash itself would be [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Syntax).  It describes no provision for redirection to be performed without being associated with a command, but really that's a technicality, because **a redirection can *be* a command by itself**.

That's actually better conveyed by the POSIX docs, which describe the form of [*simple commands*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) this way:

> a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.

That's pretty clear in allowing a command consisting only of variable assignments and redirections, of which a command consisting only of a single redirection is one case.  The spec later reinforces that by explicitly describing the behavior of commands that do not contain any command name.

The Bash manual is consistent with the above, but not as specific.  Furthermore,

- Its section providing [a high-level description of shell operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation) describes at step (3) that it parses [all] the non-comment input into simple and compound commands.  Redirections are performed later, at step (5), so every redirection must be part of a command.
- From [its section on redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections):

  > Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell.

These also make it clear that redirections are associated with commands.

#### Your code

The `while` condition in your sample code is given as `! > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080`.  Per the manual, a list is required at that position, minimally composed of a single, optionally negated pipeline, which must contain at least one command consisting of at least one word.  But although it cannot be empty, a command does not need to contain a *command name*.  Commands without command names are relatively frequent in shell scripts -- this is the classification of lines that contain only variable assignments, for example.

In this case, the list contains a single negated (`!`) pipeline, consisting of a single command, consisting of nothing but a redirection.  The Bash manual does not speak directly to this case, but in practice, it follows POSIX here.  POSIX specifies that if a command contains redirections but no command name, then the redirections are performed in a subshell environment.

A command may fail on account of other commands performed during the expansion failing, or on account of any of its redirections failing.  Otherwise, a command with no command name succeeds without doing anything further, just as if it were the command `:`.  In your case, the command will succeed if the redirection succeeds and fail if it fails.  The negation operator will reverse the logical sense of that for the status of the pipeline, and that will serve as the exit status of the list containing it.  Ultimately, that's what the `while` command will use to determine whether to execute the commands in its body.

Overall, then, your `while` command tests whether it can open `/dev/tcp/localhost/8080` for writing.  If so, it does nothing else (not even hold that file open).  If not, it prints "waiting..." to the standard output, sleeps for 3 seconds, then repeats from the beginning, with the redirection attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Well, an "official document" is the *bash **man** page*. It says that first the redirection is set up, and then the command is executed. Since it is obviously allowed that a bash line does not contain any command (otherwise, empty lines in a bash script would be forbitten), my interpretation is that bash then just sets up the redirection and then, due to the lack of a command, does not execute anything.
"
So it is valid, although I would prefer to explicitly use the "official" null command, i.e.

```
: > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080

> /dev/tcp/localhost/8080 :
```

respectively in your case, since you want to invert the exit code,

```
! : > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080
```

Comment: Certainly blank lines are allowed in `bash` input, but that does not imply that empty *commands* are allowed, nor does it speak to the meaning of a redirection or a `!` that is not associated with a command.